# Ruby on Rails + Formtastic + jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm trying to install the jQuery UI datepicker with Formtastic. I followed http://blog.brzezinka.eu/webmaster-tips/ruby/ruby-on-rails-formtastic-jquery-ui-datepicker so I:

1. added jQuery UI (confimed it works with other elements)
2. installed Formtastic 2.0.2 (confimed it works with other elements)
3. Adjusted application.js
4. Adjusted Formtastic.rb as described in the tutorial and the comments
5. Changed view

I keep getting 'Formtastic::UnknownInputError' on <%= f.input :dtstart, :as => :datepicker %>. I googled and searched for this error but can't find a clue in which direction to look. Anybody here an idea? I'm on rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you're using `:as => :datepicker`, you have to create a custom input for it.

As the documentation suggests, create a new file in `app/inputs` named `date_picker_input.rb`

```
class DatePickerInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def input_html_options
    super.merge(:class => "datePicker")
  end
end
```

All you have to do is trigger the JQuery UI addon in your `application.js`:

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker();
```

If you don't want to bother creating a custom input, you can just add the class directly as in:

```
<%= f.input :date, :input_html => { :class => 'datePicker'} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this was a long time ago, but for future generations this is because the article is missing a lot for Rails 3. He updated the original article to point at the plugin version of the file: http://github.com/demersus/formtastic_datepicker_inputs

Answer (score 0):

Yet again, a long distant answer from the original post. In the event though, you ended up here searching for how to do this with Formtastic 3.1 and Rails 4 (may work otherwise, but untested), [all I did was look at how ActiveAdmin implements theirs.](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html#datepicker) With the formtastic gem in your Gemfile and installed, you can add your own `as: :datepicker` capability to the `input` method used by Formtastic [by following the pattern they describe in their documentation](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs).

Simply put, create the file/directory below (if the directory doesn't already exist) and simply add this:

```
# <your app>/app/inputs/datepicker_input.rb
class DatepickerInput < ::Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
   def input_html_options
      super.tap do |options|
         options[:class] = [options[:class], "datepicker"].compact.join(' ')
         options[:data] ||= {}
         options[:data].merge! datepicker_options
      end
   end

  private
  def datepicker_options
     options = self.options.fetch(:datepicker_options, {})
     options = Hash[options.map{ |k, v| [k.to_s.camelcase(:lower), v] }]
     { datepicker_options: options }
  end 
end
```